cv2.undistortPoints result seems wrong
I'm trying to find 3d position of some points based on camera position and distortion.
I tried to use undistortPoints function of opencv in python and the result for zero distortion is not even near to the distorted points.
R_mtx, _ = cv2.Rodrigues(rvec_final) 
cam_final = np.array(cam_final, dtype=np.float64) 
dist_coeffs = np.array(dist_coeffs, dtype=np.float64) 
# Convert image_points to float32 before passing to undistortPoints 
image_points = np.array([[p['x_calib'], p['y_calib']] for p in points2d if p['side'] == 'Class ' + str(i + 1)],dtype=np.float64) 
image_points = image_points.reshape(-1, 1, 2) # Undistort the 2D points 
undistorted_points = cv2.undistortPoints(image_points, cam_final, dist_coeffs, P=cam_final)  
# Reshape undistorted points to avoid unnecessary nested arrays 
undistorted_points = undistorted_points.reshape(-1, 2)

But when i define distraction 0 instead of getting nearly same results i get odd results. These are my values:
results.calculate R [[ 0.75292126 -0.65808195  0.00614274]
 [-0.13613247 -0.16486962 -0.97687561]
 [ 0.64387695  0.73467419 -0.21372016]]
Camera matrix (cam_final):
[[2.60314e+03 0.00000e+00 9.59500e+02]
 [0.00000e+00 2.60314e+03 5.39500e+02]
 [0.00000e+00 0.00000e+00 1.00000e+00]]
dist_coeffs [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]

For example there are some of my 2d positions for distored and undistored
points
Original Point 8: x = 1021.0, y = 433.0
-> Undistorted Point 8: x = 1565.0, y = 449.0
idx 9
Original Point 9: x = 1049.0, y = 296.0
-> Undistorted Point 9: x = 1392.0, y = 418.0
idx 10
Original Point 10: x = 147.0, y = 661.0
-> Undistorted Point 10: x = 1398.0, y = 329.0
idx 11
Original Point 11: x = 270.0, y = 336.0
-> Undistorted Point 11: x = 637.0, y = 430.0
idx 12
Original Point 12: x = 830.0, y = 334.0
-> Undistorted Point 12: x = 1029.0, y = 521.0
idx 13
Original Point 13: x = 1155.0, y = 307.0
-> Undistorted Point 13: x = 1194.0, y = 303.0

What am i doing wrong? I checked everything.
